# codeigniter stored procedure for bulk insert in MsSql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I am creating a system in Codeigniter where I can upload a file (txt & xls) bulk insert to MsSql using stored procedure, my problem is I dont know how to use parameters but my stored procedure is working working properly, I just need some help about my codes on how do it properly.

here are my current codes:

**Controller**

```
function upload_gen048()
```

{

```
$data['filedate']=$this->input->post('fiil');


        $this->load->model('navi_model');
        $query = $this->navi_model->upload_gen048($data);
        $this->db->query("call {gen048upload} ");
```

**Model**
I think this is where I mess up a lot.

```
function upload_gen048($data)
{


$x = explode('.',$data['fiil']);
//print_r ($data);

$qString = "";
$qString .= '[dbo].[gen048upload] '; //STORED PROCEDURE
$qString .= "'" .$data['fidedate']."'";
echo $qString;
```

**Stored Procedure**
My SP is working properly, but I think of putting some of codes that may help you to figure out my problem.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[gen048upload]
(
        @fileDate VARCHAR(20)

)

AS BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @sql varchar(8000),@sourceTable varchar(500), @dynamic varchar(8000), @tablesuffix varchar(10)
select @tablesuffix=upper(substring(datename(m,convert(datetime,@fileDate)),1,3))+convert(varchar,year(convert(datetime,@fileDate)))
print @tablesuffix


 declare @currmonth varchar(10)
 select @dynamic=''

create table #logs(
i int identity(1,1),
tableName varchar(50),
status varchar(30)
)

set @sourceTable ='gen_048_'+@tablesuffix
insert into #logs(tableName,status) select @sourceTable,'CREATED'
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = @sourceTable)
BEGIN
    set @sql = '
    CREATE TABLE '+@sourceTable+'
    (

......
    )
    '   


print @sql
exec (@sql)

SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE TABLE #temp (WHOLEROW VARCHAR(8000))

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp1 (WHOLEROW VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL2 = 'BULK INSERT #temp1
    FROM ''Y:\FTP\RMT\' + @fileDate + '.txt' + '''
    WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''char'', KEEPNULLS, FIRSTROW=1, MAXERRORS=0, ROWTERMINATOR =  ''' + CHAR(0x0A) + ''')'

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL2

    IF EXISTS (
            SELECT fdate
            FROM gen048_fdate
            WHERE fdate IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW, '|', 7), CHAR(9), '')
                    FROM #temp1
                )
        )
    BEGIN

        SELECT 'Error: File Exists, Duplication is not allowed', @fileDate

    END
    ELSE BEGIN

        INSERT INTO gen048_fdate (fdate)
        SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',7), CHAR(9), '')
        FROM #temp1
```

Comment: I edited my model and I think I am know what I want to do but I cant still find a way how to code it. I am thinking of getting the data from the data from "fiil" and after I load my SP I will send it to "@sourcetable" it has something to do with the parameters, but I cant code it.